# Sets $A$ and $B$ and their Union

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If $A$ is a set with $m$ elements and $B$ is a set with $n$ elements and if $A\cap B=\varnothing$, then $A\cup B$ has $m+n$ elements. What is a proof for this statement?

Comment: It's as easy as PIE.

Comment: (Principle of Inclusion-Exclusion)

Comment: ...or just count!

Comment: Sometimes that is the _definition_ of "+".

Comment: I'd go with induction on the cardinality of the smaller set. Which would be no more than a fancy way of expressing "just count".

Answer (score 2):

The union of two sets is the set of all elements of each set. If the two sets do not have any elements in common, then the union set contains all elements in $A$ along with all elements of $B$. The commonly cited formula is:

$|A \cup B| = |A| + |B| - |A \cap B| = m + n - 0 = m + n$

Comment: Can you prove the inclusion-exclusion formula without _already_ knowing that $|A\cup B|=|A|+|B|$ for disjoint $A$ and $B$?

Answer (score 1):

Proof is

Using inclusion-exlusion principle we have

$$|A{\cup}B|=|A|+|B|-|A{\cap}B|$$

Here as $|A{\cap}B| = 0$

$$=>|A{\cup}B|=|A|+|B| = m+n$$

Comment: Can you prove the inclusion-exclusion formula without _already_ knowing that $|A\cup B|=|A|+|B|$ for disjoint $A$ and $B$?